# How to create an uncoverable container in HTML document?

Tags: html, css, security, overlay

In order to print, I have to render a HTML document and add some header on top. The thing is, that nothing below the source of the header should be able to cover my header. Today, if I add the header like this

```
<html>
   <body>
     <div>My Header</div> <!-- added by me -->
      ...
      foreign HTML
      ...
   </body>
<html>
```

I have the problem that the `foreign HTML` may define an element (eg `div`) that lays on top of my header. I have to prevent this.

Even an `iframe` can get overlayed. Or someone defines `"display: none;"` for the element I used for the header later.

I cant divide header and body message because the result must be ONE HTML document. But I must be sure that my header is visible and not covered or manipulated by something else.

The good thing is, that I'm sure than no JS is running.

Any ideas?

Comment: you cannot protect against someone setting its `display` to `none`. But who is this *someone* that would do that ? In terms of overlaying it, if you have to protect agains ***any*** overlay, then you need to put it at the end of the html document, and set its `position` to `relative/fixed/absolute` (*depending on needs*) and `z-index` to `2147483647` which is the largest allowed. But if others are allowed to add code they can change that to something lower and then overlay it.

Comment: "Someone" might be users who think they are funny overlaying my header on printouts. Or even evil attempts to fake the origin of such message. I get some HTML from them and have to add header and prepare for printing. The HTML is then finally printed from other tools in the process. So I cant split/divide header from message.

Comment: If you get HTML from them that goes on top of your header, just edit it so that it doesn't... all of these solutions will prevent anything that is not intended to break your site, and if you get something like that it is an easy fix.

Comment: @VolkerSchmid if you allow arbitrary html/css in your page, then there is **no way** to make sure. But you should **not** allow arbitrary html/css in your page, it is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: So it turns out to be impossible. This is what I also thought but I was not sure. So, as long as people can edit the foreign part in the same document, there always will be a way to overlay or manipulate my header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best i can come up with is using a sandboxed `iframe` with `srcdoc` (*not supported by IE*)

Something like

```css
iframe {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  header
</div>

<iframe srcdoc="
<style>
  body{margin:0} 
  #header{color:red} /*this will not work*/
  #test{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;} /*even fixed positioning is maintained inside the iframe*/
</style>

<div id='test'>user content</div>
" sandbox=""></iframe>
```

But again you have to at least sanitize the user contents so that they do not break out of the srcdoc string.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly, on Windows we use the ActiveX version if IE to display the document. So this is not working for us :-(

Comment: This is working since IE10, so we used this as the best option. Because of this, I marked this as the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the only option you have, i think, is to set z-index property to a high value - 9999 for example. so that other elements can't cover it.
remember, it's position property should be; fixed, relative or absolute.
good luck

Answer (score 0):

You could move the header div out of the `<body>` tags and set the CSS for `<body>` to have `padding-top` that is equal to the height of the header div (either with a set value of dynamically with JS). Then set the `position` of `<body>` to `relative`, so the only way a foreign HTML can be on top of the header is if it has `position: fixed` and `top` smaller than the height of the header.

Giving your header the maximum `z-index` allowed can also help!

Comment: Thanks. But you already lined out how to break it (...if it has position: fixed and top smaller than the height of the header...). So it can get broken by the foreign HTML, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing this for. Is this an assignment? There's literally no way to stop someone from editing HTML. Once you serve the page, if the user wants to inject HTML to put content on top of your header, he will find a way. All he has to do is undo the HTML/CSS you've put in place to stop him, which is always possible.

Comment: So it turns out to be impossible. This is what I also thought but I was not sure. How to mark such a question at StackOverflow (if not possible to solve)? Found nothing in help or FAQ for impossible to solve questions :-(